# Swift generic without force unwrap downcast

Tags: swift, generics, generic-programming

I try to create some generic based code:

```
protocol ViewModelsCreator {
    associatedtype T: EditItemViewModelType
    func editItemViewModel<T>() -> T
}

class PlacesListViewModel: ViewModelsCreator {
    typealias T = EditPlaceViewModel
    func editItemViewModel<T>() -> T {
        return EditPlaceViewModel()
    }
}

class EditPlaceViewModel: EditItemViewModelType {}

protocol EditItemViewModelType {}
```

The playground shows error:

> cannot convert return expression of type 'EditPlaceViewModel' to
>   return type 'T'

and suggest to use

```
return EditPlaceViewModel() as! T
```

Is there any solution to avoid this (as! T) force unwrap code? I think compiler should figure out that EditPlaceViewModel is EditItemViewModelType and should satisfy this generic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the `<T>` in the `ViewModelsCreator` protocol and the `PlacesListViewModel` class.

```
protocol ViewModelsCreator {
    associatedtype T: EditItemViewModelType
    func editItemViewModel() -> T
}

class PlacesListViewModel: ViewModelsCreator {
    typealias T = EditPlaceViewModel
    func editItemViewModel() -> T {
        return EditPlaceViewModel()
    }
}
```

You can also remove the typealias and replace `-> T` with `-> EditPlaceViewModel` in the `PlacesListViewModel` class. It works either way but this is more explicit.

```
class PlacesListViewModel: ViewModelsCreator {
    func editItemViewModel() -> EditPlaceViewModel {
        return EditPlaceViewModel()
    }
}
```

Comment: Also in the 2nd example the typealias can be removed as the compiler can now infer the proper alias.

Comment: @Cristik I'm curious about what changed (in "can _now_ infer") and when; can you elaborate a bit? Thanks!

Comment: @matt I meant "now" as in the second answer, not from a chronological perspective (I think the inference is present since protocols with associated types). Sorry for the confusion